# ETFs mimicking world economy?

Tags: portfolio-management, etf

We can find ETF that usually mimick some stock index, for e.g. SP500 has SPDR, Dow Jones Industrial Average has DIA, etc.

Does an ETF that tracks all these indexes exist?

Comment: Closest I know is VT: Vanguard Total World Stock ETF. It tracks something called FTSE Global All Cap Index.

Comment: ACWI tracks the MSCI All Country World Index; very liquid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the objective is to mimick all the world's equity stock markets in a single ETF there would appear to be 2 choices:

VT which tracks something called FTSE Global All Cap Index with a very low expense ratio

ACWI tracks the MSCI All Country World Index; it is very liquid

Comment: I've been searching. What do you think of Lyxor UCITS ETF?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about  Lyxor UCITS ETF MSCI World. It trades in Euros, has over 1 billion EUR in assets, expense ratio of 0.30%, less liquid than the other two, Bloomberg id is "WLD FP Equity". Thanks for mentioning it. MSCI World is deifferent from MSCI All country: it does not include Emerging Markets.

Comment: but there's this Lyxor UCITS ETF MSCI All Country World C-EUR, also. Thanks for the info. ;)

Comment: Yes! Very good! That one is called "ACWI FP Equity" in Bloomberg. A good find.